# Событие добавления нового элемента

Tags: jquery, javascript, dom

Как можно поймать событие, когда динамически добавляется новый элемент?

```
.live('ready' function(){}) не работает
```

Comment: Для начала, метод **.live()** - устаревший и рекомендованно использовать метод [.on()](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/On). Во-вторых, **.ready()** - устанавливает обработчик готовности дерева DOM. И в-третьих, хорошо бы чуть подробнее о том, чего хотите добиться.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$('#someId').on('appendCompleted', function(){
    console.log('append completed');
});

$('#container').append(function(idx){
    $('#someId').trigger('appendCompleted');
    return '<div id="anotherDiv">...</div>';
});
```

###### UPD: более каноническое решение

```
$.when($('#container').append('<div id="anotherDiv">...</div>'))
 .done(function(){
    console.log('append completed');
})
```

- [.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)
- [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)
- [jQuery.when()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/)

Answer (score -1):

```
$("div#container").delegate("div#obj", "click", function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("chosen");
});
```

[источник](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

Comment: - div#container - bad,
- div#obj - bad,
- \#container - good,
- \#obj - good

Comment: а что плохого в точном селекторе?

Comment: надо понимать, что когда движок jQuery видит селектор вида `#someText`, то он тут же выполняет `getElementById`, и не выполняет парсинг всего селектора регулярными выражениями, к тому же зачем делать div#obj, как будто у вас есть ещё img#obj или p#obj, идентификаторы же должны быть уникальными

Answer (score -1):

Если используете версию дж квери последнюю, то лучше использовать `on`.

И ставить обработчик не на сам объект а через делегирование, вот так:

```
$('body').on('click', '.elem', function(){});
```